# PostgreSQL materialized view is blocking reads while being refreshed

Tags: javascript, python, postgresql, flask, materialized-views

I have a complicated query that takes 2 to 3 minutes to run. This is naturally unacceptable response time for our javascript and python flask web app.

In order to increase performance I made the query a materialized view and scheduled it to refresh every 30 minutes. This works very well, however, I'm getting an issue where the actual refresh blocks reads from the web app. Thus, every 30 minutes the app stalls for 2 to 3 minutes. What is a good way to resolve this? My first thought was to add a cache to the python backend, but I'm feeling there should be a simpler solution I can do - in postgres itself maybe?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out there is a "CONCURRENTLY" keyword I wasn't aware of:

> Refresh the materialized view without locking out concurrent selects on the materialized view.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html

Comment: REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY name Is this resolved your problem? Now I'm also facing the same issue you mentioned in the question.

Comment: @JijoAlexander Yes it resolved the issue.

Comment: That solved my issue as well, thanks for the tip!